# Does every $A$ is $B$ and every $B$ is $A$ imply that there is some element that is either $A$ or $B$?

Tags: logic

Apologies if I'm being vague with the title, I will try to hammer down a concrete example.

I am given the following fact (*): Every wealthy person is happy, and every happy person is wealthy. Does this imply that there is some person who is wealthy or happy?

My initial thought was yes, but then I thought about the event where there was no one happy or wealthy. Would * still hold? If * is still true, but the conclusion is false, then * would not imply the conclusion.

In general, I guess what this boils down to is if the "for all" quantifier holds for empty sets. If $S$ is an empty set, would $\forall s\in S, P(S)$  be true, no matter what statement $P(S)$ was?

Comment: Fact (*) holds when the set of wealthy people is empty and the set of happy people is empty. So, no, there is no implication that there is some person that is both. Yes, $\forall s\in\varnothing P(s)$ (note the lower case $s$, not $S$) holds; this is called a truth "by vacuity."

Comment: By the way I'm doubtful of the equality you mention between set of happy and set of wealthy persons. But that may be a question to be discussed in an other forum!

Comment: Interesting, today I learn that there is such a thing as a vacuous truth

Comment: Please, note that in terms of sets "every A is B and every B is A" means simply that $A=B$. Thus, both sets may be *empty* and the fact above still holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last sentence is correct. If a set $S$ is empty then $\forall s\in S, P(s)$ holds.

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning that this concept has a name: [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

Comment: @Arthur Thanks for the comment. Interesting to note that there is no similar Wikipedia entry in French (I'm French). And I don't know a similar expression in French either.

Comment: Strainge; there is one in (mexican) Spanish: "por vacuidad".

Answer (score 1):

The statement $\forall s\in S, P(s)$ is true if $S$ is empty.  When we know $S$ to be empty we say the statement is vacuously true.  Similarly if you are told that all $A$ are $B$ and all $B$ are $A$, it could be that there are no $A$s nor $B$s

Answer (score 1):

> Every wealthy person is happy, and every happy person is wealthy. Does this imply that there is some person who is wealthy or happy?

No, it does not.

You're right about the empty set.

Using https://www.umsu.de/trees/, we have

[image]

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know these websites existed. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, @YipJungHon; you can show your appreciation by upvoting.